# nested condition in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation

I am looking for below result.

- india without scanner IP blocked
- india without scanner IP nonblocked
- india with scanner IP blocked
- india with scanner Ip non blocked
  where ip1,ip2=>Scannner IP

I have tried the below one ..but it's showing only "india without scanner IP blocked" count

```
| eval BlockedStatus = case ( src !="ip1" OR src !="ip2.*" OR blocked=1,"india without scanner IP blocked", src !="ip1" OR src !="ip2*" OR  blocked=0 ,"india without scanner IP nonblocked" ,src ="ip1" OR src ="ip2" OR blocked=1,"india with scanner IP blocked", src ="ip1" OR src ="ip2" OR blocked=0 ," india with scanner Ip non blocked ")
| stats count by eventtype,BlockedStatus 
| rename eventtype as "Local Market",count as "Total Critical Events"
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic in the `case` statement is faulty.  Just about everything will match `src!=ip1 OR src!=ip2 OR blocked=1`.  I think some of the `OR`s should be `AND`s and that some parentheses are needed.

Maybe this is closer to what is intended?

```
eval BlockedStatus = case ( src !="ip1" AND src !="ip2" AND 
  blocked=1,"india without scanner IP blocked", src !="ip1" AND src !="ip2" AND 
  blocked=0 ,"india without scanner IP nonblocked" ,(src ="ip1" OR src ="ip2")
  AND blocked=1,"india with scanner IP blocked", (src ="ip1" OR src ="ip2") AND
  blocked=0 ," india with scanner Ip non blocked ", 1==1, "Error")
| stats count by eventtype,BlockedStatus 
| rename eventtype as "Local Market",count as "Total Critical Events"
```

Comment: have tried the same but again its giving only "india without scanner IP blocked" count

Comment: Please share some sample events.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703855/splunk-case-with-wild-card-search-for-ip-address