# splunk case with wild card search for IP Address

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

can you please help me with below ..

```
index=xyz 
| eval BlockedStatus =  
case(Like(src,"14.19.106.%") AND blocked=1 ,"Q Blocked", 
            Like(src,"150.29.121.%") AND blocked=1,"Q Blocked",
            Like(src,"14.19.106.%") AND blocked=0,"Q Not Blocked", 
            Like(src,"150.29.121.%") AND blocked=0,"Q Not Blocked",
            NOT Like(src,"14.19.106.%") AND blocked=1,"Non Q Blocked", 
            NOT Like(src,"150.29.121.%") AND blocked=1,"Non Q Blocked",
            NOT Like(src,"14.19.106.%") AND blocked=0,"Non Q Not Blocked", 
            NOT Like(src,"150.29.121.%") AND blocked=0,"Non Q Not Blocked")            
| stats count by eventtype BlockedStatus 
| rename eventtype as "Local Market", count as "Total Critical Events"
```

since we have data for where `src=150.29.121.23` and `blocked=1` but above query giving me result as

```
"Non Q Blocked" instead of "Q Blocked"
```

Not sure what went wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Something must be different in your data from the question because the query works in my sandbox.

[image]

Comment: thanks @RichG ..
Now can see we have event count as Q Blocked , Q Not Blocked, Non Q Blocked and Non Q Non blocked ..
Now i want every  BlockedStatus  should give total count in grouping manner ..
eg. 
Q Blocked = 12  Local Market
     11 foo
     10 ES
     11 GR
==============
Total   = 44

Q Not Blocked = 32  Local Market
         10 foo
         20 ES
         15 GR
========
Total    77 

I have added this in end of the existing query but unable to find the sum and pattern ...
| top showperc=f BlockedStatus by eventtype
|stats list(*) as * by BlockedStatus | sort -count